# google analytics event tracking not working within firefox 20.x, 21.x

Tags: google-analytics

google analytics event tracking works fine within firefox 17.x, chrome 27.x and IE10, but NOT working within firefox 20.x, 21.x.

debug info within firefox 20.x, use firebug:
200 OK
    http://www.google-analytics.com/_*utm.gif?utmwv=5.4.3&utms=4&utmn=946065331&utmhn=10.1.62.32&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1600x900&utmvp=1600x468&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=zh-cn&utmje=0&utmfl=11.7%20r700&utmdt=Alfresco%20%C2%BB%20%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3%E8%AF%A6%E7%BB%86%E4%BF%A1%E6%81%AF&utmhid=365910971&utmr=0&utmp=%2Fshare%2Fpage%2Fsite%2Feb-docs%2Fdocument-details%3FnodeRef%3Dworkspace%3A%2F%2FSpacesStore%2F9914e708-d043-4146-98df-034625744db0&utmht=1371792749668&utmac=UA-41710059-1&utmcc=*_utma%3D267551246.1346337148.1371715580.1371780993.1371792718.3%3B%2B__utmz%3D267551246.1371715580.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmu=q~

Network params:
utmac     UA-XXXXXXXX-1
utmcc     _*utma=267551246.1346337148.1371715580.1371780993.1371792718.3;+*_utmz=267551246.1371715580.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);
utmcs     UTF-8
utmdt     Alfresco
utmfl     11.7 r700
utmhid     365910971
utmhn     10.1.62.32
utmht     1371792749668
utmje     0
utmn     946065331
utmp     /share/page/site/eb-docs/document-details?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/9914e708-d043-4146-98df-034625744db0
utmr     0
utms     4
utmsc     24-bit
utmsr     1600x900
utmu     q~
utmul     zh-cn
utmvp     1600x468
utmwv     5.4.3

HTML code:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();
 </script>
 </head>

 <a href="xxx" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'eb-docs', 'yulan' ,'xxx']);">xxx</a>
```

Thanks.